# My navigation bar is not responsive - HTML/CSS

Tags: css, templates, blogger

I have a template in blogger.com that was working pretty well until recently. The navigation bar for the website stopped working and can't link to the pages -it doesn't highlight the differente pages. The mobile version runs perfectly. Can someone help me to identify the problem?

```
    background:#F1F1F1;
    height:55px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:9999;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}

.slicknav_menu {
    display:none;
}   

    #navigation .container {
        position:relative;
    }

.menu {
    float:left;
}

.menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:12px;
    position:relative;
}

.menu li a {
    font:$(navbar.text.font);
    font-weight:400;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    color:$(navbar.text.color);
    line-height:55px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:inline-block;
    -o-transition:.3s;
        -ms-transition:.3s;
        -moz-transition:.3s;
        -webkit-transition:.3s;
}

ul.sub-menu li:after {
  content: "|";
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #565656;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: can u show the HTML?